# Spark Sql registerTempTable and registerDataFrameAsTable difference

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

what is difference between  `registerTempTable` and `registerDataFrameAsTable` method in Spark SQL and which is better in which scenario.

Answer (score 10):

### Spark >= 2.1

There is a new [`createGlobalTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@createOrReplaceTempView%28viewName:String%29:Unit) which can used to register cross-session views:

> Its lifetime is the lifetime of the Spark application, i.e. it will be automatically dropped when the application terminates. It's tied to a system preserved database `_global_temp`, and we must use the qualified name to refer a global temp view, e.g. `SELECT * FROM _global_temp.view1`.

### Spark >= 2.0

`registerTempTable` has been deprecated in favor of [`createTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@createTempView%28viewName:String%29:Unit) and [`createOrReplaceTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@createOrReplaceTempView%28viewName:String%29:Unit) with the former one throwing and exception if the view already exists.

### Spark < 2.0

#### PySpark

While there is no practical difference between these two there is a difference in execution strategy:

- `SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable` calls `registerDataFrameAsTable` method on JVM SQL context
- `DataFrame.registerTempTable` calls `registerTempTable` on JVM data frame, which calls `registerDataFrameAsTable` method on JVM SQL context

#### Scala

- `DataFrame.registerTempTable` calls `registerDataFrameAsTable` method on SQL context
- `SQLContext.registerDataFrameAsTable` is a private method not accessible outside `org.apache.spark.sql` package.

To keep things simple it is probably a good idea to stick to `registerTempTable` as well.

Comment: is the registered table distributed like dataframe/rdd? Also are the operations on it distributed?

Comment: @Ajinkya It is.